# reversing elements of an integer array

Tags: arrays

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int reverse(int a[20],int n);

    int main()
     {
     int a[20];
      int n;
      printf("enter the number of elements \n");

      scanf("%d",&n);
      printf("enter the array elements\n");
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        scanf("%d ",&a[i]);
      }
      reverse(a,n);

      return 0;
   }
     int reverse(int a[20],int n)
    {
     for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
       {
       printf("%d ",a[i]);
         }
    return 0;

    }
```

here if I input n=4 then during runtime i have to take 5 elements and then it reverses.For eg if i take n=4 and then for no of elements i have to take 1,2,3,4,5 and then only output is coming as 4 3 2 1.Why? is my logic wrong? also in this code I am unable to take the number of elements of  arrays in a straight line, like 1 2 3 4.When I am entering the number each number is entering in new line .I am a novice programmer in C and thus having these doubts.Please anyone explain...

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the extra space after `%d` in your `scanf` line where you accept array elements i.e.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   scanf("%d ",&a[i]); //should be scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

Change that and you're good to go.

Comment: @user8971 please accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @ Rahul Nori,I am sorry but i couldn't get you.What do mean by accepting the answer? Do I have to like or upvote this or something like that?

Comment: @user8971 I am sure you'll be able to see a blank tick next to the answer,you need to click on that to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your entire program refactored to work correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverse(int a[20], int n)

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    int n;
    printf("enter the number of elements \n");

    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter the array elements\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    reverse(a,n);

    return 0;
}

int reverse(int a[20], int n)
{
    int mid = n/2;
    for (int i=0; i < mid; ++i)
    {
        int temp = a[n-i-1];
        a[n-i-1] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only had to run it till half the elements, earlier you were getting the original array back.